# How do I match data from 2 dataframes with not the same number of rows and input values from one into the other in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a question regarding using one dataframe (called pricing), which has 30 rows, and another called nop, which has 1000 rows.

the Pricing dataframe has a column called Price that has data that I am hoping to copy over to the nop dataframe, and I want all rows on the nop dataframe populated with the Price value from the pricing dataframe. They are matched by the column Id.

I was thinking of doing a for loop within a for loop but I am thinking that there might be an easier way to do this.

```
nop['Price'] = ''

for i in nop:
    for j in pricing:
        if nop['Id'][i] == pricing['Id'][j]:
            nop['Price'][i] = pricing['Price'][j]
        else:
            j+1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could use join method to join the two dataframes on common key, which id `id` column in your case. To demonstrate same, I have created two dataframes with`id` as common key and performed `join` as in below code

```py
import pandas as pd
pricing_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'price':[10,20,40,21,99]})
nop = pd.DataFrame({'id':[3,4,1,2,5,1,2,2,5,3,1,4,4,1,4], 
                    'product': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']})
```

```py
pricing_df
```

[image]

```py
nop
```

[image]

by calling join method on joining key would yield below results.

```py
nop.join(pricing_df.set_index('id'), on='id').sort_values('id')
```

[image]